# REST - How to get the maximum of a number

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, rest

A list has an int field named `AccountNumber`. Everytime a new record is created through the `NewForm.aspx` I need to fill out the field `AccountNumber` with max (`AccountNumber` for existing items) + 1.

I need to do it using javascript + jquery. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$orderby` and `desc` to sort the items based on descending value of Account No. You can also use `$top` to return top n items. `$select` would be used for returning the field you want.

Eg: `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List')/items?$orderby=AccountNo desc&$top=1&$select=AccountNo`

You can then add 1 to the returned `AccountNo`.